# knockout dirty flag code not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Just started with knockout and need to implement page change warning. Following is the code snippet. I just need an alert pop up as warning if any change is made on the page.

```
function parseViewModel() {

    var viewModel = JSON.parse(getState());

    viewModel.checking = ko.observable(false);
    viewModel.Slider = new ko.observable(100 - viewModel.Slider);
    viewModel.CausalsList = buildHierarchy(viewModel.Causals);
    viewModel.Causals["-1"] = "Total Marketing Budget";
    viewModel.GeographiesList = ko.observableArray(gl);
    viewModel.Geographies["0"] = "All Geographies";
    viewModel.ProductsList = ko.observableArray(pl);
    viewModel.Products["0"] = "All Products";
    .
    .
    .

    return viewModel;
}

function bindModel() {

    model = parseViewModel();

    ko.dirtyFlag = function (root, isInitiallyDirty) {
        var result = function () { },
        _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root)),
        _isInitiallyDirty = ko.observable(isInitiallyDirty);

        result.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
            return _isInitiallyDirty() || _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
        });

        result.reset = function () {
            _initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
            _isInitiallyDirty(false);
        };

        return result;
    };


    model.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(model);
    model.isDirty.subscribe(function () {
        alert("Page change warning!");
    });

    ko.applyBindings(model, $('#const').get(0));
    ko.applyBindings(model, $('#buttonDiv').get(0));
}
```

Referred Ryan Niemeyer's blog. Unfortunately, it's not working anymore. Any insights please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to subscribe to `model.dirtyFlag.isDirty` in your case rather than `model.isDirty`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arni05/M2BCb/2/
Tried to put something together in this fiddle although not a working one. Can you please throw some light here?

Comment: I am not sure exactly the scenario that you are working with in the fiddle, but maybe this one will help you get further.

Comment: Hey Ryan, I have a form with some data bindings done. Now on that model, I have to set a dirty flag which on turning true calls another js method having alert box call. In fiddle, I tried to create two fields showing binding on them and then set dirty flag on model. However, it's not working.

Comment: Hey Ryan, something is setting dirtyFlag to true in my code. I tried resetting in bindinghandlers - update but doesn't work. Is there any way to call reset on load? The element to which I am binding test{} in my original code goes to edit mode on load and hence sets dirtyFlag to true. Tried to represent code here

http://jsfiddle.net/arni05/M2BCb/  Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is by using customBinding. I'm not that familiar with KO either but this might be something you're interested on.

Basically you would do is :-

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myFunction = {
    update : function(){
                //do something
             }
}
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

And call it on your element using :-

```
<h1 data-bind="myFunction:{}"></h1>
```

Also, a jsfiddle to show how it works. (If you change the value of the First Name and focus out of it then the customBinding gets triggered. )

http://jsfiddle.net/3vuTk

Not sure if it's the best practice though.

Comment: Go with @RP Niemeyer. He knows what he's talking about more than I will ever know. :D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arni05/M2BCb/2/
Tried to put something together in this fiddle although not a working one. Can you please throw some light here?